# GradleCompatible error after adding some dependencies?

Tags: android-studio, dependencies

When I add two (1.2.) dependencies I get `Manifest merger failed error.`
A hint for dependency is below:

> 1. implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
> 2. implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'

I am using android studio 3.4.1 + gradle version 5.1.1

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.houselocation"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

> `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

```
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-beta2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
}
```

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0, 27.1.1. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and
>   com.android.support:design:27.1.1 less... (Ctrl+F1)  Inspection
>   info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries,
>   that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility
>   is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is
>   not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible
>
> Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx.* can not
>   be combined but found
>   IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='com.android.support',
>   myArtifactId='support-vector-drawable', myVersion='28.0.0',
>   myPacking='aar', myClassifier='null'} and
>   IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='androidx.cursoradapter',
>   myArtifactId='cursoradapter', myVersion='1.0.0', myPacking='aar',
>   myClassifier='null'} incompatible dependencies less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and
>   libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such
>   incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support
>   libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version
>   lower than your targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible

**and Gradle sync issues**

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute
>   application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried like this, 
 select Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar.
It worked for me.
For additional information Check this link https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate